# For Loop based on item chosen in combobox

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, combobox

For example i have items in combobox like this:

```
    cIndexchoice.addItem("AAA");
    cIndexchoice.addItem("BBB");
    cIndexchoice.addItem("CCC");
    cIndexchoice.addItem("DDD");
    cIndexchoice.addItem("EEE");
    cIndexchoice.addItem("FFF");
    cIndexchoice.addItem("GGG");
    cIndexchoice.addItem("HHH");
    cIndexchoice.addItem("III");
```

Each component from combobox has equivalent String Arrays like this:

```
      String[] AAA = { some strings here };
      String[] BBB = { some strings here };
      String[] CCC = { some strings here };
```

And now i have loop works on Arrays like this (example for AAA):

```
        for (int i = 0; i < AAA.length; i++)
        {
            ConstructorURL spolka = new ConstructorURL(startDate, endDate,
                    AAA[i]);
            DataGeting new1 = new DataGeting(spolka.constructURL(),
                    HowManyDaysStrdv, i);
            listEntities[i] = new1;
        }
```

And loop should work on what user chose in combobox, and i have no idea how to do it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you post [code that compiles](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It's not clear what happens now, why it's wrong, and what you want to happen. Please explain.

Comment: my main class: http://pastebin.com/4hm4ukDj 

Please take a look at line 225, 226, 229, 240, 246. I know that in loop i should use arrays not String and code does not compile. I can make it using if but it is very ugly solution and i looking for something clever. And have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Read again the link I posted in my previous comment. You can show the problem in less than 400 lines. Post a **minimal** "compilable" code which shows what the problem is **and what you want it to do**.

Comment: Ok sorry i did not notice you hyperlink :)

Comment: Ok maybe now: http://pastebin.com/
And i want if user choice form combobox BBB then JTextArea display each element from BBB arrays. What should i do in loop that works depends on combobox?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom object that contains two properties:

1. The value to be displayed in the combo box
2. The array or Strings related to that value

Then you will need to create a custom renderer so that the "value" is displayed in the combo box. See [Combo Box With Renderer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/) for the way to do this.

Then you add an ActionListener to the combo box and in the processing code you get the selected item and cast it to your custom class. Now you can access the Array of Strings from your class and display them in a text area.

Comment: To be honest i do not get it :( ok i create new object contains combobox name and the array

 public SectorSelected(String str, String[] sectorList)

but i have no idea what next.

Comment: @user3361567 `i have no idea what next.` - did you add the SectorSelected object to you combo box and create the custom renderer?

Comment: No, but i found another way to do it, i will use hashmap and the key will be value from combobox.

Comment: @user3361567, yes that is the other approach I was going to suggest. It is the same idea, but the point of using a custom Object is that all the data is together in the object and not in an external data source like the Hashmap.

Comment: Yes and thank you for your time :) but i am a beginner in java and the easiest way is to use hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

And the solution using hashmap:

```
public class testing extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

    private JTextArea taResultArea;
    private JComboBox cIndexchoice;
    private JButton Start;

    public testing()
    {
        setSize(700, 700);
        setLayout(null);
        taResultArea = new JTextArea();
        taResultArea.setEditable(false);
        taResultArea.setBounds(300, 15, 350, 600);
        add(taResultArea);

        Start = new JButton("Run Simulation");
        setLayout(null);
        Start.setBounds(20, 500, 150, 50);
        // adding buttons to the main window
        add(Start);
        Start.addActionListener(this);

        String[] listOfElements = { "AAA", "BBB", "CCC" };
        cIndexchoice = new JComboBox(listOfElements);
        cIndexchoice.setBounds(20, 50, 100, 20);
        add(cIndexchoice);
        cIndexchoice.addActionListener(this);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        testing window = new testing();
        window.setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource() == Start)
        {
            String[] AAA = { "A", "AA", "AAA", "AAAA", "AAAAA", "AAAAAA" };
            String[] BBB = { "B", "BB", "BBB", "BBBB", "BBBBB", "BBBBBB" };
            String[] CCC = { "C", "CC", "CCC", "CCCC", "CCCCC", "CCCCCC" };

            HashMap<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
            map.put("AAA", AAA);
            map.put("BBB", BBB);
            map.put("CCC", CCC);

            String[] SectorSelected = map.get(cIndexchoice.getSelectedItem().toString());

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(SectorSelected));

            for (int i = 0; i < SectorSelected.length; i++)
            {
                taResultArea.append(SectorSelected[i] + "\n");
            }
        }

    }
}
```